# Java RMI via Webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, rmi, tunneling

I'm searching for a possibility to run a java RMI application via webservice or an internet protocol.

is there any framework or solution that says "I can run RMI as WebService with WS-Security" or "I can run RMI via HTTPS" etc.

or is tunneling RMI over HTTP or SSH the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask why you're intending on using two remoting technologies over one another?

Edit: [RMI over SSL](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/rmi/socketfactory/SSLInfo.html)

Comment: it is a prototype for a protcol in a research project.
first the protocol was implemented as a webservice and now the technology shall be changed to java RMI.

but there also shall be a fall back strategy for this prototype to run it as a webservice again.

i think the major points are the firewall aspect (because webservices dont have problems there) and the second is the security aspect - therefore HTTPS not HTTP or a WS with WS-security

Comment: Easiest way is RMI over SSL, see my edit. RMI over WS is also possible, albeit more involved.

Comment: thx a lot for the SSL solution. could you be so kind to explain the way RMI over WS in a very short and simple way

Comment: ok thx. i think this fits my needs at the moment. this article is from 2002 and describes the development of such a framework - do you know if there are any frameworks available now? have you heart about XSOAP (aka SoapRMI) http://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/

Comment: Glad to hear that it does. I don't know any other ones, because I haven't done so myself, I find it quite inefficient to run two remoting protocols like that. But I understand your requirements are different. As such I haven't used XSoap. Tick my reply as the answer if you're happy with it. Good luck.